# Safe to reboot just after running a command?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I want to make a linux machine reboot after running some code inside a cronjob.

The code basically looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
do_something
reboot
```

where `do_something` is basically:

```
function do_something {
    local REPORT_URL=https://example.com/services/status
    local PAYLOAD='{"message":"Update script run with success.","code":'$UPDATE_SUCCESS'}'
    curl -X POST --form "payload=$PAYLOAD" "$REPORT_URL"
}
```

Is there any possibility that `do_something` does not finish all its jobs (e.g. i/o operations) before `reboot` is run?

In such a case, what would be the best solution among these ones:

- Add `sync` before `reboot`.
- Add `sleep 5` before `reboot`.
- Add `sync` and `sleep` before `reboot`.

Comment: What exactly is `do_something`? Show its code please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a problem on any popular system from the last decade (or two?). `reboot` will only change the runlevel, or target, or whatever concept your system is using to track what state it should be in. In practice doing either a reboot or shutdown will just trigger the events which are needed to put it in that state. Normally this involves unmounting all the filesystems, and the kernel will flush/sync all the data before that happens.

So no. On any modern Linux distribution, the sync is not needed.

PS. This assumes that `do_something` doesn't spawn any background tasks. In that case, the question is completely different and more to do with service synchronisation. If `do_something` finishes all operations and exits, you're good.

Comment: Nice, enlightening answer, I learnt something which I hadn't expected when I read the Q.